# Spring test H2 truncates nanoseconds during consequente queries

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, h2

I am using H2 in-memory database in Spring integration test.

I have following column on my entity

```java
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDateTime;
```

However I noticed some problems in H2, sometimes it truncates nanoseconds part eg:

Saved datetime: 2020-07-02T13:36:40.459145400

After few moments 2020-07-02T13:36:40.459145

It seems that H2 is not able to store nanoseconds and just round up nanoseconds part.

My integration tests cannot pass because of this inconsistency. Could You please help ?

Comment: H2 can store nanoseconds, but you need `TIMESTAMP(9)` column for that purpose. The `TIMESTAMP` data type without parameter holds only microseconds as required by the SQL Standard.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and adding `@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP(6)")` didn't resolve it. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This boils down to nanoseconds resolution. Java has greater nanoseconds resolution (6 digits) than H2 (9 digits).

For me `TIMESTAMP(9)` did the trick:

```kotlin
@Column(name = "creationDate", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP(9)")
    val creationDate: LocalDateTime,
```

Comment: Is there a consistent way to do this with precision parameters of @Column annotation?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to avoid the truncation of nanosaconds, when LocalDateTime would be persisted into the H2 database. I used Hibernate 5.x and H2 database 2.1.214.
Firstly, an inherited class would be extended from org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect like below.

```
package com.example;
    
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;

import java.sql.Types;
    
public class ExtendedH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {
    public ExtendedH2Dialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp(9)");
    }
}
```

Then, the above class would be set as hibernate dialect property.

```
hibernate.dialect=com.example.ExtendedH2Dialect
```

In this case, the production code is untouched.

I hope it help.
Best Regards.